# Fixed position command prompt in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, command-line-interface

Is there a way to have a command prompt (just a [`question`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_callback) prompt, or something similar) fixed to the bottom of the Terminal, and to log output above it, using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

A really bad example:

```
Your favourite food is sushi.
Your favourite food is chicken.
Your favourite food is okra.
--> What is your favourite food?
```

So essentially, I'm looking to have the user always able to type, and have input echoed above the prompt.

```js
interface.question("What is your favourite food?", function(answer) {
    // output the answer above where this prompt was
    // and somehow keep this same prompt where is is
});
```

The particular application I'm hoping to use this in is a simple IRC client, where I have a spot for the user to type, and have all the output (what the user has typed, and what others have also typed) outputted above where the user is typing. The lines in the diagram below are imaginary.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
| Stuff                                                              |
| Stuff                                                              |
| Stuff                                                              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| --> The user can type here                                         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Apparently not.  None of the answers proposed addresses the question.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Try or say in comment why the answer is not good.

Answer (score 16):

## [Serverline module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverline)

[image]

```js
process.stdout.write("\x1Bc")
console.log(Array(process.stdout.rows + 1).join('\n'));

const myRL = require("serverline")

myRL.init()
myRL.getRL().question("What is your favourite food? ", function(answer) {
  console.log(`Your favourite food is ${answer}.`)
});

function main() {
  let i = 0
  setInterval(function() {
    const num = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1
    i++
    console.log(i + " " + num() + "." + num() + "." + num() + " user connected.")
  }, 700)
}
main()
```

**Old version :**

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24519813/revisions

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution (tested with node v6.4.0 on macos):

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

// Logs a message keeping prompt on last line
function log(message) {
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
  console.log(message);
  rl.prompt(true);
}

// Testing the solution

rl.question('Enter something...:', userInput => {
  log('You typed ' + userInput);
  rl.close();
});

log('this should appear above the prompt');
setTimeout(
  () => log('this should appear above the prompt'),
  1000
);
```

Comment: Simple, intuitive and works really well! Thanks. I changed it a little bit from the above answers to make the question thing loop recursively whenever input is entered.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm using [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) for solve that kind of issues.. It's has all those thigs resolve already.. It's easy to use and you have diferents kind of propmt types.

Here a litle example form the doc:

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');
inquirer.prompt([/* Pass your questions in here */]).then(function (answers) {
    // Use user feedback for... whatever!! 
});
```

Comment: -1, Inquirer doesn't solve that problem very well. I've setup a console.log every 1 second on Windows and upon a new stdout, the old inquirer prompt remains on the new stdout line and reappears only when you start typing.

Answer (score -1):

just use the [readline](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) core module:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What do you think of node.js? ", function(answer) {
  console.log("Thank you for your valuable feedback:", answer);
  rl.close();
});
```

This will solve your problem:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var fav_foods = [];

var ask_question = function() {
  rl.question("What is your favourite food? ", function(answer) {
    fav_foods.push(answer)
    fav_foods.forEach(function (element) {
       console.log("Your favourite food is " + element)
    })
    ask_question()
  });
}

ask_question()
```

Comment: And how would this stay where it is?

Comment: what do you mean? also have a look at the more complex example (end of the page) that you can find under the given link

Comment: I ran [this](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_tiny_cli) example, and it's close to what I'm trying to do. What I'd like is to have the prompt always at the bottom of the terminal and `console.log()` (or some other function) above the prompt.